# PDF becoming corrupted after signing

Tags: pdf, adobe, acrobat

I'm writing a TypeScript library that signs PDFs. For most PDFs it works fine. However, some PDFs render in Acrobat as corrupted.

I can't seem to figure out what's wrong with them. I noticed that those files that get corrupted use XRef streams, but when I parse the XRef stream of the signed file, it seems ok.

I also looked at the whole structure of the file, and it seems like everything is ok (no broken objects etc)

I find debugging PDFs really hard, since everything I get from Acrobat is "There was an error opening this document. The file is damaged and could not be repaired."

Here's the [resulting PDF](https://ufile.io/uxq3gr6o) that renders as corrupted if someone wants to take a look.

EDIT: The source code is really huge, I can post it if you want. But, I'd prefer if someone helps me debugging the PDF file itself, and tell me if there is a way to debug PDF files more easily

Comment: Did my answer help? Or is this still an open issue?

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I solved it, I think there were actually some more issues. I'll try to remember them and post an answer just to try to help others, if they stumble across something similar

Answer (score 1):

The cross reference stream of your PDF is 88 bytes long, matching 22 object entries for `/W[1 3 0]`. Given the `/Size 23`, though, there should be 23 object entries.

Furthermore, inspecting the entries there is a shift, the entry for object 1 points to object 2, the entry for object 2 points to object 3, etc.

Probably, therefore, you dropped object 1.

There appear yet to be other issues. E.g. in spite of the `/Size 23` you have an object 24.

You should completely overhaul the cross reference stream generation.